# Fix a compile error when comparing a T[keyof T] and a string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

When I compare `T[keyof T]` and `string`, where `T` is a generics, I get this error.

This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)

```
function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
  if ((a[orderBy] === 'abc') && (b[orderBy] === 'def')) {
    // Error. This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)
    return 1
  }
  return 0;
}
const x = {name: 'abc'}
const y = {name: 'def'}
descendingComparator(x, y, 'name')
```

How to fix this compile error? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to fix this:

```
function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
  if (((a[orderBy] as string) === 'abc') && ((b[orderBy] as string) === 'def')) {
    // Error. This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)
    return 1
  }
  return 0;
}
const x = {name: 'abc'}
const y = {name: 'def'}
descendingComparator(x, y, 'name')
```

A better way would be:

```
function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
  if ((typeof a[orderBy] === 'string' && a[orderBy] === 'abc') && (typeof b[orderBy] === 'string' && b[orderBy] === 'def')) {
    // Error. This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)
    return 1
  }
  return 0;
}
const x = {name: 'abc'}
const y = {name: 'def'}
descendingComparator(x, y, 'name')
```